# How to I cast a different type to a buffer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, mobile

I am trying to convert obj-c code to swift and I came across this problem where I have a buffer of type UnsafeMutablePointer<Float> and I need to convert it to UnsafeMutablePointer<DSPComplex> DSPComplex is a struct that stores data using ordered pairs of floating numbers.

Below is the obj-c code:

```
float *dataBuffer

(COMPLEX *)dataBuffer
```

Answer (score 1):

How about to try this?

```
// UnsafeMutableRawPointer is C style raw array. 
// UnsafeMutablePointer is array of specific type.
// Convert UnsafeMutableRawPointer to UnsafeMutablePointer : 
let ptr = rawPtr.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int16.self)
let ptr = rawPtr.assumingMemoryBound(to: COMPLEX.self)
```

Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2428188-assumingmemorybound